# General Advice with apollo hooks and too many re renders

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

background: I am trying to achieve a file upload with DropZone to s3 and graphql serving presigned url for puts and gets and while it might not be perfect it does work. The issue I am having now is when I add in useMutation to push the result to graphlql end which write to mongodb database I am getting too many re renders so looking for advice on how to really understand whats going on here. As ugly as my code may be the upload to s3 works once I don’t have addFileS3(file) the addFileS3(file) is call useMutation to grpahql to write the result to mongoDB so I can retrieve the file at  later point so i assumed the best 
place for it was the response from axios.

```
const DropZone = ({ folderId, folderProps }) => {
  const [createS3File] = useMutation(ADD_FILE_S3);
  const addFileS3 = (file) => {
    createS3File({
      variables: {
        folderId: folderId,
        fileName: file.name,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("data", data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
  const {
    acceptedFiles,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
  } = useDropzone({ accept: "image/*, application/pdf" });
  const [
    getPutURL,
    { loading: loading_url, error: error_url, data: data_url },
  ] = useLazyQuery(GET_S3_PUT_URL);
  if (loading_url) {
    console.log("loading");
  } else if (error_url) {
    console.log(error_url);
  } else if (data_url) {
    const results = data_url.PUTURL;
    results.map((file) => {
      const fileResult = acceptedFiles.filter(function(fileAcc) {
        return fileAcc.name === file.name;
      });

      const options = {
        params: {
          Key: file.name,
          ContentType: file.type,
        },
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": file.type,
        },
      };
      axios
        .put(file.url, fileResult[0], options)
        .then((res) => {
          //once i add the below here or outside axios post it goes mental on uploads
          addFileS3(file);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
        });
    });
  }

  const acceptedFilesItems = acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
    return (
      <li key={file.path}>
        {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
      </li>
    );
  });

  const uploadDocs = () => {
    let files = [];
    acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
      const fileObj = { name: file.name, type: file.type };
      files.push(fileObj);
    });

    return getS3URLResult(files);
  };

  const getS3URLResult = async (files) => {
    getPutURL({
      variables: {
        packet: files,
      },
    });
  };



  return (
    <StyledDropZone>
      <div className="container">
        <Container
          {...getRootProps({ isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject })}
        >
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
        </Container>
        {acceptedFilesItems}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => uploadDocs(acceptedFiles)}>Upload</button>
    </StyledDropZone>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making axios request during render 'flow', not in event handler/chain. It's called, changes state and causes next rerendering - infinite loop.

Both mutation and lazy query have possibility to use `onCompleted` handler. This is a place to chain/invoke next action (using `data` result parameter).

... alse hanlder should not return anything (`return getS3URLResult(files);`) - just call it (`getS3URLResult(files);`) or directly `getPutURL`.

### update

Probably you're looking for something like this:

```
const DropZone = ({ folderId, folderProps }) => {
  const {
    acceptedFiles,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
  } = useDropzone({ accept: "image/*, application/pdf" });

  const uploadDocs = () => {
    let files = [];
    acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
      const fileObj = { name: file.name, type: file.type };
      files.push(fileObj);
    });
    console.log("uploadDocs, from acceptedFiles", files);
    // return getS3URLResult(files);
    getPutURL({
      variables: {
        packet: files,
      },
    });

  };

  const [
    getPutURL,
    { loading: loading_url, error: error_url, data: data_url },
  ] = useLazyQuery(GET_S3_PUT_URL, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log("PUT_URL", data);

      const results = data.PUTURL;
      results.map((file) => {
        const fileResult = acceptedFiles.filter(function(fileAcc) {
          return fileAcc.name === file.name;
        });
        const options = {
          params: {
            Key: file.name,
            ContentType: file.type,
          },
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": file.type,
          },
        };
        axios
          .put(file.url, fileResult[0], options)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("axios PUT", file.url);
            // addFileS3(file);
            createS3File({
              variables: {
                folderId: folderId,
                fileName: file.name,
              },
            })
          })
          .catch((err) => {
          });
      });

    }
  });

  const [createS3File] = useMutation(ADD_FILE_S3,{
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log("ADD_FILE_S3", data);
      //setUploadedFiles( uploadedFiles,concat(data.somefilename) );
    }
  });                         

  const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState( [] );


  const acceptedFilesItems = acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
    return (
      <li key={file.path}>
        {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
      </li>
    );
  });   

  const renderUploadedFiles ...

  return (
    <StyledDropZone>
      <div className="container">
        <Container
          {...getRootProps({ isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject })}
        >
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
        </Container>
        {acceptedFilesItems}
        {uploadedFiles.length && <div class="success">
          {renderUploadedFiles}
        </div>}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => uploadDocs(acceptedFiles)}>Upload</button>
    </StyledDropZone>
  );
};
```

Some optimalizations should be added (useCallback), not placed for clarity.

For more readability and optimization (limit rerenderings) ... I would move almost all (processing) into separate subcomponent - pass `acceptedFiles` as prop, render upload button inside.

Comment: thank you for your response so i can see when i add the onCompleted to useLazyQuery i can console the data which is the initial data_url array if i make the mutation for addFileS3 accept an array of file objects then that should work but the reason i wanted it in the axios query was after each file upload is successful to then tak that individual file detail and call mutation, is this possible as how would i be sure the file actually uploaded with axios before storing the result permanently in my database.thanks again

Comment: thanks very much definitely given me couple options here so really appreciate that particularly the onCompleted i knew you could do something with it but wasnt sure how to implement. need to get my head around React and what causes re renders.

Comment: in class components state or props change, it's much easier ... in functional almost everything ;)

Comment: ye i am only learning React a little after hooks came out and i found functional components much easier to understand or so i thought but i suppose ill have to learn class components at some point too. cheers

Comment: they are esier (shorter) as 'presentational' (mainly view, with limited logic) at cost of fighting with always rerendered/run body (prevent redeclarations, redefinitions, useMeno, useCallback, useEffect ... moving more complex logic into custom hooks) ... in class you have more classic look and feel, more granular control, earlier used more as 'container' (data+logic)